# Installing AWS SDK for PHP via source fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, guzzle

Downloading the last sourcecode of AWS SDK PHP from github in .zip and trying to load it trough:

```
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Common\Aws;
```

and getting this error when it tries to load the Guzzle library:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unable to open /config.php for reading' in /srv/www_nfs_desarrollo/vhosts/desarrollo.techmaker.net/httpdocs/oaviles/src/Guzzle/Service/AbstractConfigLoader.php on line 120`

Didn't touched anything from the source. I can't use composer or any other dependencies manager, so only way to use this SDK is via the zip download. The dependencies are suposed to be included on the .zip but autoloader is not working at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had a bad line on my index.php